# For external links on my webpage, should I use a redirector page or just link direct to the external URL?

Tags: redirect, seo

just wondering if I should be using a 'redirector' type page or link directly to the external pages on my site - currently I use a redirector page to track what links are being clicked on (which simply takes an ID, looks up the URL in the database, and then does a Response.Redirect(*URL*);

From a SEO point of view, is this a good idea/bad idea? I understand it can add a few milliseconds extra to the external page load time whilst it looks up the actual URL, but am not too concerned about this. I also get the benefit of tracking the clicks accurately, but are the pros/cons of using a redirector vs the actual link? Am I worrying about something I don't need to?

Thanks

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199731/best-practice-how-to-track-outbound-links for an seo friendly way of tracking ourbound links.

Comment: Thanks, already using jQuery so thats a bonus!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shouldn't influence your ranking.
It's a common technique and used by many major sites...

Is there a special reason why you look up the URLs in a database? You could simply transfer the redirect url directly as post/get parameter:

```
http://www.onedaysalefinder.co.nz/redirect?p=http://www.foo.bar
```

To prevent any kind of abuse you should check if the user came from your site by checking the referrer.

It's also a good idea to prevent search engines from indexing your script.
Do this by modifying your robots.txt

Comment: Thanks, good detail, and I will check the referrer as well. I was pondering this eariler, but I wonder what the actual abuse could be, what nasty things could someone do? All I would do is log the URL into the DB (via parameters and HTML encoding of course!), and then redirect to it? I guess 'brand reputation' perhaps if nasty people post a link on their site, at first glance it looks like its going to my site, but its actually going to head off somewhere else?

Comment: Thats exactly the point!


Spammers could use your site as free redirection service through a "clean" domainname.


Another possibility to secure your redirection is to sign the redirection with a hash using for example HMAC.
HMAC is a simple hash algorithm with a secret key.
If you pass the hashed target as a second parameter, your script could simply check if it was signed by your site.

Comment: I ended up simply adding the URL, ie redirector.aspx?siteid=1&url=http://www.1-day.co.nz - but on the redirector page I dont do anything with it, still look up the URL from the database based on the ID.

Answer (score 1):

You could combine both approaches by supplying the full URL as a GET argument to the redirector page.  This would allow you to track clicks, include the original URL text in your page, and also remove the need for database lookup.

Comment: I think this is the best option, to pass both ID and the actual URL through, so I can still track it, and the URL is 'exposed' for both the user and search engines. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I do not quite understand what you want to do... But if you want to put external link on your site or web page, and you do not know  whether is that link (URL) in some black lists, therefore you should to use, for example, site with redirect function, like this: http://example.com/go?URL_TO_BE_VIEWED ! Then put code on your page:

```html
<a href='http://example.com/go?http://some_url.url' target='_blank'
   rel='nofollow'>http://example.com</a>
```

(with valid tags)!!!

Good luck, man!