# mysql stuff when click on link then go to link

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a phpBB forum, some posts contains Links... I want to count how many times the link on the post has been visited...

I think that catching the "click" on the link, make php and mysql stuff and, then after all, go to the external link is the best way ... but I dont know how to do that.

Its possible to interrupt the link click, modify some things and then load de link as always? (maybe using ajax or jquery)

A link example could be:

www.google.com

The mysql table called phpbb_likes contains:

```
Like_id
Post_id
User_id
Like_time
```

I know how to add a new like using something like this:

```
Insert INTO phpbb_likes ("Post_id","User_id","Like_time") VALUES ("2355","45","1343546456");
```

But the problem is interrupting the link redirecting to make that sql query

Any Idea?
thanks

Comment: It sounds like you want to attach a JavaScript handler to the link's `click` event and make an AJAX request to your server in that handler.  Google things like "JavaScript click handler" and some tutorials on AJAX in PHP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best practice: How to track outbound links?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199731/best-practice-how-to-track-outbound-links)